# Visual Studio 2015 hanging after adding Azure SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015

So I set up the latest Azure SDK that integrates with Visual Studio 2015. It all seemed to work well and I was happily playing around with it for an hour or more in my small .net 4.6 MVC app with 3 projects in the solution. I went in to the Azure web portal and set up a new resource group there, and when I went back to VS I refreshed the Server Explorer my resource group was visible under App Service and data from the ApplicationInsightsExtension.log file appeared when I opened the file in a tab. All fine and dandy.

However, the next time I opened the solution VS hung and wouldn't respond. The active tab is the ApplicationInsightsExtension.log file and it seems to be trying to connect to Azure but is getting stuck. I've tried everything including rebooting etc but nothing works. I'm also opening VS in Admin mode

Is there a setting somewhere in the config / project files that specifies what tabs are opend when you open a solution? I'm thiinking if I stop the ApplicationInsightsExtension.log file from opening that might fix the issue. However I've looked in the .csproj and csproj.user files and can't see any setting that might correspond to this.

[Visual Studio load error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqKtC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reset your settings to prevent VS to restore your opened tabs.

1. **Ensure your Visual Studio is Closed.**
2. Navigate to your solution directory in windows explorer.
3. Ensure your are displaying hidden files on Solution Explorer. View Tab -> Show/hide ribbon group/ check Hidden items checkbox.
   [image: Show hidden files]
4. A folder named **.vs** must be shown now in Windows Explorer.
5. Navigate to .vs\<**SolutionName**>\v14
6. Delete .suo file in the directory.
7. Open your solution.

Now VS will not load any tabs by default, so maybe you can see what is happening.

Hope this helps!